# Why can't I subdivide this plane normally?

Tags: objects

[image]

I'm working with a plane and trying to subdivide the plane so that I can add curvature to it.  Normal methods that have been working on other surfaces are not working on this plane.  I do not understand.

Comment: Your plane is not subdividing correctly because there aren`t sufficient vertices in the bottom edge so that each vertex on the top edge could connect with the vertex on the bottom edge. Your mesh only has two vertices in the bottom edge.

Comment: your plane is made of tris, it may be the problem? maybe give additional details?

Comment: how do you expect triangles to bend? You topology is really wrong right here, your bottom should have same amount of vertices as the top and then you need to make it into quads, not tris